# 2 vms in one cloud service only one IP?

Tags: azure

I created 2 vms, one for centos and another one for azure, I used the same cloud service, but both have the same public IP Address, why>? can I change it?

Or they have to be in different separate cloud services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, they are behind a single IP address which load balances the private IP addresses. Until recently, there was no way to get a public IP for a virtual machine.

Now, it's possible to [assign a public IP to a virtual machine](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2014/05/12/azure-vm-security-extensions-expressroute-ga-reserved-ips-internal-load-balancing-multi-site-to-site-vpns-storage-import-export-ga-new-smb-file-service-api-management-hybrid-connection-service-redis-cache-remote-apps-and-more.aspx):

> With Instance-level Public IPs for VMs, you can now assign public IP addresses to your virtual machines, so they become directly addressable without having to map an endpoint through a VIP. This feature will enable scenarios like easily running FTP servers in Azure and monitoring virtual machines directly using their IPs.
>
> We are making this new capability available in preview form today.  This feature is available only with new deployments and new virtual networks and can be enabled via PowerShell.

Typically, the load balancer is fine, but there are options if you absolutely need access to individual machines.

Answer (score 0):

Since they're in the same cloud service, they're probably behind the same load balancer, and a load balancer would only have one public IP.

So, yes, I would use different cloud services as you mentioned.